# Project Euler #14 solution takes quite a long time

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

Can anybody give me suggestions for making it faster? ([Project Euler #14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14))

```
import time
start = time.clock()

def collatzChain(n):
    count = 1
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            count += 1
            n = (n * 3) + 1

        if n % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            n = n / 2

    return count

chainLengths = []
startNum = 999999
while startNum > 1:
    chainLength = collatzChain(startNum)
    chainLengths.append(chainLength)
    startNum -= 1

print(999999 - chainLengths.index(max(chainLengths)))
elapsed = time.clock() - start
print("This program took " + str(elapsed) + " seconds.")
```

Comment: Here's a hint: store things you've already calculated and use them to speed up other calls to `collatzChain`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @drizzit and @Veedrac pointed out,
the key to solving this problem is to avoid counting the sequence twice for the same number.
You *could* build a cache yourself,
but @drizzit's answer looks especially interesting.

In addition, this is inefficient:

> ```
>     if n % 2 != 0:
>         count += 1
>         n = (n * 3) + 1
>
>     if n % 2 == 0:
>         count += 1
>         n = n / 2
> ```

Although this will make very little difference (especially after you implement the cache),
but since these conditions are mutually exclusive,
you should turn the second `if` to an `else`,
and also remove the duplication in `count` and the division:

```
    count += 1
    if n % 2 != 0:
        n = (n * 3) + 1
    else:
        n /= 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider the chains starting at 13 and 26. When you reach 26, you go over its whole chain. Later, you reach 13, and go over its whole chain too - but 13's chain is the same as 26's, only without the first number (26).

If you implemented `collatzChain` using recursion, just adding the decorator `@functools.lru_cache` would create a cache for your function, and thus prevent Python from repeating the same job twice.

Comment: `@functools.lru_cache` is a Python3 feature, but the code in OP clearly uses Python2.

Comment: Whilst this is a neat idea, recursion is extremely risky since some chains are particularly long. If you start at the wrong number with an empty cache, things will break.